# Elasticseach reindex api not reindexing all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I've recently decided to change my mapping/settings, and to do this i had to reindex all documents (5M), however, it's only reindexing 20 documents out of the 5m.

I created a new indice with same arch, but changed a lot of mappings/settings. (changing keyword type to text type, etc)

when posting to reindex with this command:

```
POST /_reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index",
    "size": 2000
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_new"
  }
}
```

it only reindexes 20 documents then shows completed. Am i missing something? Can i not change text to keyword and vice versa?

i'm on 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my mappings. I had specified an invalid type.